# How do you trigger a JavaScript event from CSS pseudo event without using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, pseudo-class

I want a JavaScript event to happen when a CSS pseudo-event takes place. Here's an example:

`element:hover {background-color: red;}`
I want it to run this code block below when the element also turns red:
`console.log("Hello, world!")`

I'm not sure if this is really possible **without** using **jQuery**, but if it is, tell me how to do this.

Comment: you can add addEventListener "mouseover" on this element

Comment: It would not be possible, you will have to use vanilla javascript or jQuery and attach a listener or event to execute your code.